# Advantages of Microsoft Enterprise Mode Schema v.2 over v.1?

Tags: group-policy, internet-explorer, schema, microsoft

Title explains it really. The company I work for is considering changing their Enterprise Schema from v.1 to v.2. I am aware that there are structural changes to the coding, however I am not aware of any prominent advantages.

From a performance perspective primarily, what are the advantages of v.2?

Comment: There is no difference in performance. The schema change was for functionality and readability.

Comment: @GregAskew Thank you for the reply, what are the functionality differences?